# Can a Perforce Workspace view contain a label?

Tags: perforce

We are using our Perforce Workspace view's to include other internal corporate "libraries" i.e.:

```
//depot/my/project/path/dev/... //workspace_name/...
//depot/some/other/library/path/dev/... //workspace_name/include/...
```

We would like to be able to specify that the included library should sync to a specific label.  I won't be modifying it, and want to make sure new updates to that library don't break my code.  In git terms this would be called a submodule.

```
//depot/my/project/path/dev/... //workspace_name/...
//depot/some/other/library/path/dev/...@label_name //workspace_name/include/...
```

But I get the following error:

> Error at line 2 of field 'View' in client specification.
>   Revision chars (@, #) not allowed in '//depot/some/other/library/path/dev/...@label_name'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible at this time. There are three ways I could see to handle this currently in Perforce:

1) Create a Perforce label which would set the version you would like in your workspace. This is a bit awkward in that you have to make sure you don't sync that set of files without referencing the label.

2) A general best practice for component based development is to have the submodules cut releases. If that was in place you could just consume the version of your choice.

3) Create an import branch that has a version of the code you want to use. You can then update it whenever you choose. That could theoretically give you the control you need with minimal maintenance overheard.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  So we plan to take the second option, that is to have the components create a branch for releases we want to snap to.  So our viewspec will look something like this:
//depot/some/other/library/path/branch_name/... //workspace_name/include/...  If I could put in a feature request to support the syntax mentioned above that would be awesome!  It would be ok that these parts of the viewspec are readonly.

Comment: These are good ideas. Also consider investigating the Perforce Streams feature, as it has a number of elements that make this component based development much easier.

Comment: Yes, streams look like they would help here, however they are a pretty big jump, and our IT still hasn't upgraded our servers to support them.  After some further experience, we have landed more on option 3 (make a "local" branch of what you need), but would LOVE for labels to be supported in the viewspec.... pretty please...